# Retrieve Eloquent Model function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, I have an Eloquent Model `Person` and a function `getSomestringFromPerson()` which is operating on the Model Person and returning a string. Now I have an AJAX request whose response is a collection of Persons. Until here I know what to do.

Now, in the JavaScript I would like do display the result of `getSomestringFromPerson()` for each `Person` in the response.
Is that possible? If yes, how? Or do I have to run the function in the Controller and include the result in the AJAX response? (That looks a bit cumbersome to me...)

Comment: What does getSomestringFromPerson() do?

Comment: @jackel414 "function getSomestringFromPerson() which is operating on the Model Person and returning a string" It does that :P

Comment: @TimLewis Haha, fair enough. I was trying to suss out whether it was manipulating data or just parsing a string (something that would be easy to do in JS), but I supposed it may not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller that handles the AJAX request, I assume it gets a collection of `People` like something like this (at a bare minimum):

```
public function handleAjax(Request $request){
    $people = People::get();

    return response()->json(["people" => $people], 200);
}
```

And then in your JS a function for handling the response:

```
$.get(URL, function(data){
    console.log(data); // Collection (js object) of `People` models.
});
```

In your `handleAjax` function, you would loop over each of your `People` and assign a property to hold the value of `$person->getSomestringFromPerson()`:

```
foreach($people AS $person){
    $person->someString = $person->getSomestringFromPerson();
}
```

Then, in your `Javascript` code, you would be able to access it like so:

```
for(var person in data.people){
    console.log(data.people[person].someString); // Should return the expected value of `$person->getSomestringFromPerson();` as defined in your function.
}
```

From there, you should be able to do whatever else it is you'd need to do with your `data.people` object.

Comment: OK. That was what I meant with "run the function in the Controller and include the result in the AJAX response"